# Celery ImportError: No module named proj

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to setup Celery with Django. I have followed the guide:

project/project/celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

then in...

```
project/project/__init__.py:


from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

project/apps/test/tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Then run:

> celery -A proj worker -l info

which gives the error:

```
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test-api/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 92, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test-api/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named proj
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your project is named `project`, not `proj`. You should use that name throughout.

Comment: What if my stuff is name correctly? How should the settings in settings.py be named, ie, should CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE have the same name as project?

Answer (score 15):

I just want to say that if you have correctly named everything and you still have the module not found error (I spent hours trying to figure this out)... Then you must place the command "celery -A proj worker -l info" above the apps branch

"The celery program can be used to start the worker (you need to run the worker in the directory above proj):" as per the docs

Comment: yeah, everything celery-related is always guaranteed to give me a headache.  you gotta admire what it gets done, but boy is it a pain to always chase down config issues.

Comment: What do you mean above the "apps" branch? `Project/Project/` ,right?