# No module named 'project_name' with Django + Celery?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, python-importlib, cookiecutter-django

Day 2 of debugging this I have to turn to stackoverflow I'm on the edge.

I used cookiecutter-django to generate my project months ago.

```
Project name
     config/settings/...
     src/
        app_name/
            __init__.py
     manage.py
```

when I create `celery.py` inside config I get an error because it is named after a package, so I googled and tried using `absolute_import` but I just went with naming the file `celery_app.py` like guys from `django-cookie-cutter` did

### celery_app.py

```
import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.base")

app = Celery("my_awesome_project") #I tried this with 10 different names, doesn't make any difference

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

### **init**.py inside config/

```
#from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery_app import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

### last lines of the traceback

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<project_name>'
```

There was a bug with `python 3.7` and `celery` where you had to downgrade `importlib-metadata` with  `pip3 install importlib-metadata==4.13.0` I am using `python 3.9.6` and have tried both downgrading and installing the latest `importlib-metadata`

I tried running all variations of `celery -A config.celery_app worker -l info` and `celery -A config.celery_app:app worker -l DEBUG` from the `root folder`

> From `cookiecutter-django README.md`:
>
> > To run a celery worker:
>
> bash cd my_awesome_project celery -A config.celery_app worker -l
> info
>
> Please note: For Celery's import magic to work, it is important
> *where* the celery commands are run. If you are in the same folder with *manage.py*, you should be right.

I am also using `redis`, I have `redis-server` running and the `localhost` running as well. Inside `redis-cli` `ping` returns `pong` so it works.

Where I started:
https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/

Posts with similar problems:
[(Django-Celery Error) ImportError: No module named myproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50035723/django-celery-error-importerror-no-module-named-myproject)
[Celery ImportError: No module named proj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920992/celery-importerror-no-module-named-proj)
[KeyError / frozen importlib._bootstrap error on second library import in spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53855836/keyerror-frozen-importlib-bootstrap-error-on-second-library-import-in-spyder)
[Error while running celery worker : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72628503/error-while-running-celery-worker-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mysite)
https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/vcqr5e/celery_does_not_discovers_tasks_inside_django/

"Working" example:
https://github.com/stuartmaxwell/django-celery-example

If anybody has had the similar error please leave some feedback I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Added

```
ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent
sys.path.append(str(ROOT_DIR / "src"))
```

to the celery_app.py just like in the regular settings and now it works.

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered with the same problem for a while before I fixed it slightly differently. My project is called 'hivemind' in the following. My settings.py is at ./hivemind/hivemind/settings.py.

In ./hivemind/manage.py:

```py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'hivemind.settings')
print("In manage.py, value of 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': {}".format(
    os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'UNSET')
))
```

In ./hivemind/hivemind/celery.py

```py
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'hivemind.settings')
print("In celery.py, value of 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': {}".format(
    os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'UNSET')
))
```

When I run the docker swarm, the celery worker outputs:

```
In manage.py, value of 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': hivemind.settings
In celery.py, value of 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': hivemind.settings
In celery.py, value of 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': settings
```

Somehow, celery.py was run twice, and the value of DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE got changed between the two runs. So I forced the issue rather than being polite about it.

In ./hivemind/hivemind/celery.py

```py
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'hivemind.settings'
print("In celery.py, value of 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': {}".format(
    os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'UNSET')
))
```

And now things seem to work OK. Eventually, I'll try to figure out where the 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' env var is being overwritten, but for now I just need it to find the settings module, and it does.

```
In manage.py, value of 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': hivemind.settings
In celery.py, value of 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': hivemind.settings
In celery.py, value of 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE': hivemind.settings
```